# Delete a row and recalculate R^2

Tags: r, row

I have coded the following in R:
User chooses a file that contains 2 columns (V1 and V2), with numerous rows (number of rows will vary depending on input file)
The script calculates the rsq of the relationship between 2 the variables.  There can be anything from 10 to 1000 rows of data depending on the input file.

I want to code the following:
The code should loop through all rows, removing/omitting/ignoring one row at a time and calculating the new rsq with this row missing. So, for example:

There are 10 rows of data and the total rsq = 0.97
Step1: The first row of data are removed from the equation
       The rsq is calculated again, but this time for 9 rows, giving rsq = 0.98.
Step 2:The 1st row is re-added and the 2nd row is removed
       rsq is calculated again
Step 3: The second row is re-added and the 3rd row is removed
       rsq is calculated again

After each loop the "new rsq" will be placed in a new column next to the row that was removed.

Can anyone advise how to do this?  I have this coded in excel and it works well but is cumbersome and therefore not ideal.

Comment: This sounds like a bootstrap. You do need to tell use what you understand to be the "total rsq" in this situation, preferably with code! It also sounds like a homework assignment, so if you can place a context around this it may reduce the concerns that we are participating in academic indiscretions.

Comment: More like a LOO estimate, no?

Comment: Roughly how many rows are in your dataset?

Comment: Off-topic: This seems to be a bootstrap, yes. But I've not quite seen it this way. Usually, it's a sampling (with/without repeats). Why do it this way? Seems not a good choice of bootstrapping to me.

Comment: In case it is homework, just a hint:  `newvalue[j]<-some_func(data[-j,])`

Comment: I probably should have said 'jack-knife' rather than 'bootstrap'.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the replies.  I've edited my original question in the hope of clarifying what I'm asking.  This is certainly not homework.  If i'd had homework like this in school i'd have run a mile!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to do something like this?

```
# Make some sample data
set.seed(1095)
data <- data.frame( V1 = 1:10 , V2 = sample.int(5 ,10 ,repl = TRUE ) )

# Use sapply to get r2 removing each row at a time
r2 <- sapply( 1:nrow(data) , function(x) ( cor( data[-x,1] , data[-x,2] ) )^2 )
# Combine into a data frame
newdata <- cbind( data , r2 )
newdata
#      V1 V2        r2
#   1   1  5 0.2526316
#   2   2  3 0.4657601
#   3   3  5 0.3204721
#   4   4  5 0.3691612
#   5   5  1 0.5405405
#   6   6  3 0.3769480
#   7   7  3 0.3840426
#   8   8  2 0.3409425
#   9   9  1 0.2725806
#   10 10  3 0.4986702
```

Comment: Hi Simon, Thank you for this.  I think this is exactly what I need.  I've modified your code to use my own data and it runs perfectly. Although, it is giving different results from my .xls, I will have a play around.  I can't thank this forum enough for the input it provides, especially when I'm so poor at describing what it is I need help with!

Comment: @user2224979 you are welcome! Check the type of r2 that excel is calculating. By default `R` uses Pearsons product moment correlation coefficient. I'm not sure if Excel does the same? It could also be a rounding/display issue with Excel. Basically, I trust R because the help page describes exactly the method used, and you can check the source if you really want. Try different `cor` methods, e.g. `cor( data[-x,1] , data[-x,2] , method = "spearman" )` and see if they tally.

Comment: Cheers Simon. Yes, this is why I'm keen to move the excel code I have to R, because with R I know exactly what I'm getting!

Comment: @user2224979 what for instance is the value you get for the first row? I see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#As_squared_correlation_coefficient) that R^2 equals the square of Pearson so perhaps you just need to square the values? I edited the code to reflect this.

Comment: I've just compared `=INDEX(LINEST(B2:B11,A2:A11,,TRUE),3,1)` and `=PEARSON(A2:A11,B2:B11)^2 ` in Excel with `cor(x, y)^2` and `summary(lm(y ~ x))$r.squared` in R and all four give me the same result. (Clearly Excel data was 2 rows of 10 numbers in cells A2:B11)